# What is the difference between DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl and TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, textbox

For an example,

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox txtbox = e.Control as TextBox;
     if (txtbox != null)
     {
          //
     }
```

and

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     Control ctl = e.Control;
     DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl dText = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)ctl;
     if (dText!= null)
     {
          //
     }
```

What is the advantage DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl instead TextBox?

Help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` is derived from `TextBox` and it has some properties related to the `DataGridView` behavior.

Straight from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxeditingcontrol.aspx):

*The DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl class is a specialized type of TextBox control that implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl interface, allowing it to be hosted in a DataGridViewTextBoxCell when the cell is in edit mode.*

Handle the EditingControlShowing event to perform custom initialization of the editing control when a cell enters edit mode. To customize the display characteristics of the control, set the properties of the object returned by the DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs.CellStyle property rather than setting the properties of the control returned by the DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs.Control property.